# Periodically pull a specific folder from one git repository to another

Tags: git, git-clone, git-pull, git-subtree, sparse-checkout

I have a large git repo R1 ~30GB in size that has a large folder F1 roughly ~15GB in size. I cannot modify this repo since the repository has a high frequency R/W operations all the time.

I want to create another git repo R2 that periodically pulls folder F1 from R1 into F2 in R2 in a fast and efficient manner.

I have tried git subtree split on R1 but that is too slow, takes ~30 min. For every update in F1 in R1, git subtree split takes ~30 min every time which is not feasible.

I have also tried git sparse-checkout that works superb locally, i.e., I am able to create a local repo R2 with only F1 from R1 that syncs F2 with F1 in fast and efficient manner but I cant do the same in remote version of R2.

Any help is appreciated!